# Raspberry Pi Fedora 18 ARM Remix Remote Desktop from Windows 7

Tags: raspbian, remote, windows, vnc, rdp

I've installed the Fedora 18 ARM Remix for Raspberry Pi onto the SD card of my RasPi (type B). When connected by HDMI, Fedora and XFCE4 come up fine and without the HDMI i'm able to login through SSH easily from my other Windows box in the same network. The Pi is connected by LAN cable to a simple home router which assigns private IP addresses in 192.168...

The problem is getting remote desktop through xrdp or vnc in this FEDORA 18 ARM (rpfr18). Remote desktop is quite simple to get up and running in Raspbian and I was able to 'sudo apt-get install xrdp vncserver' after which the remote desktop was reachable directly through mstsc and a VNC Client respectively from my Windows 7.

On Fedora I've installed xrdp and vncserver and have started them yet I'm not able to connect from Windows. I have done a fair amount of googling yet am unable to get remote desktop working on this Fedora on Pi from Windows 7. Help much appreciated...

This is what I've done so far through a putty SSH session as sshd comes up at boottime:

```
[root@pkrpfr18 prateek]# cat /etc/issue
Fedora remix release 18 (Raspberrypi Fedora Remix)
[prateek@pkrpfr18 ~]$ uname -a
Linux pkrpfr18 3.6.11 #1 PREEMPT Fri Feb 15 14:07:09 EST 2013 armv6l armv6l armv6l GNU/Linux
[prateek@pkrpfr18 ~]$ pifconfig
lo
          inet addr:127.0.0.1   Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING

eth0      HWaddr b8:27:eb:e2:37:6f
          inet addr:192.168.1.3 Bcast:192.168.1.255   Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST

[prateek@pkrpfr18 ~]$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 697.95
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : BCM2708
Revision        : 000f
Serial          : 0000000099e2376f
[prateek@pkrpfr18 ~]$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         446688 kB

[root@pkrpfr18 prateek]# yum update
No Packages marked for Update
[root@pkrpfr18 prateek]# yum install xrdp tightvnc tightvnc-server tightvnc-server-module tigervnc tigervnc-server tigervnc-server-module x11vnc freerdp freerdp
Package xrdp-0.6.0-0.7.fc18.armv5tel already installed and latest version
Package tigervnc-1.2.80-0.10.20130314svn5065.fc18.armv5tel already installed and latest version
Package tigervnc-server-1.2.80-0.10.20130314svn5065.fc18.armv5tel already installed and latest version
Package tigervnc-server-module-1.2.80-0.10.20130314svn5065.fc18.armv5tel already installed and latest version
Package tigervnc-1.2.80-0.10.20130314svn5065.fc18.armv5tel already installed and latest version
Package tigervnc-server-1.2.80-0.10.20130314svn5065.fc18.armv5tel already installed and latest version
Package tigervnc-server-module-1.2.80-0.10.20130314svn5065.fc18.armv5tel already installed and latest version
Package x11vnc-0.9.13-4.fc18.armv5tel already installed and latest version
Package freerdp-1.0.1-7.fc18.armv5tel already installed and latest version
Package freerdp-1.0.1-7.fc18.armv5tel already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@pkrpfr18 prateek]# yum update xrdp tightvnc tightvnc-server tightvnc-server-module tigervnc tigervnc-server tigervnc-server-module x11vnc freerdp freerdp
No Packages marked for Update
[root@pkrpfr18 prateek]# find / -name xrdp
find: `/proc/5400': No such file or directory
/etc/sysconfig/xrdp
/etc/xrdp
/etc/logrotate.d/xrdp
/usr/share/xrdp
/usr/sbin/xrdp
/usr/lib/xrdp






[root@pkrpfr18 prateek]# ls /etc/xrdp/
km-0407.ini      km-040c.ini      km-0419.ini      rsakeys.ini      startwm-bash.sh  xrdp.ini         xrdp.sh_bak
km-0409.ini      km-0410.ini      km-041d.ini      sesman.ini       startwm.sh       xrdp.sh

In xrdp.sh, have had to change
SBINDIR=/usr/local/sbin to SBINDIR=/usr/sbin because there are no file there.
[root@pkrpfr18 prateek]# ls /usr/local/sbin/
[root@pkrpfr18 prateek]#
[root@pkrpfr18 xrdp]# /bin/bash /etc/xrdp/xrdp.sh
Usage: xrdp.sh {start|stop|restart|force-reload}
[root@pkrpfr18 xrdp]# /bin/bash xrdp.sh start
xrdp is already loaded
[root@pkrpfr18 xrdp]# /bin/bash /etc/xrdp/xrdp.sh restart
Restarting xrdp ...
Stopping: xrdp and sesman . . .
Started: xrdp and sesman . . .


[prateek@pkrpfr18 ~]$ whoami
prateek
[prateek@pkrpfr18 ~]$ vncserver

New 'pkrpfr18:1 (prateek)' desktop is pkrpfr18:1

Starting applications specified in /home/prateek/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/prateek/.vnc/pkrpfr18:1.log

[prateek@pkrpfr18 ~]$ cat /home/prateek/.vnc/pkrpfr18:1.log

Xvnc TigerVNC 1.2.80 - built Mar 20 2013 07:34:55
Copyright (C) 1999-2011 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11303000, The X.Org Foundation

Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension VNC-EXTENSION
Initializing built-in extension GLX

Fri Mar  8 01:41:05 2013
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
[prateek@pkrpfr18 ~]$ vncserver -list

TigerVNC server sessions:

X DISPLAY #     PROCESS ID
:1              1106
prateek@pkrpfr18 ~]$ cat /etc/services | grep vnc
corel_vncadmin  2654/tcp  corel-vncadmin  # Corel VNC Admin
corel_vncadmin  2654/udp  corel-vncadmin  # Corel VNC Admin
[prateek@pkrpfr18 ~]$


Have Tried from Windows 7 to connect using mstsc, VNCViewer, TigerVNC Viewer TightVNCViewer on 192.168.1.3 and at ports :0, :1, :3389, :5900, :5901
Nothing worked as they ALL get timed out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer a while back through superuser.com. It was due to the firewall which I disabled using:

> systemctl stop firewalld.service

Src: https://superuser.com/questions/577689/raspberry-pi-fedora-18-arm-remix-remote-desktop-from-windows-7

Also of interest: https://superuser.com/questions/634628/is-there-a-script-to-add-port-forwarding-rule-in-home-router